# How can I stop items being duplicated in SQLite database?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Here is my code where I add items to SQLite database

```
public partial class BirdPages : ContentPage
    {
        private SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection;
        public BirdPages(string BirdNames, Button BirdSelect)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();
            BirdNameCall.Text = BirdNames;
            AddToList = BirdSelect;
            
        }

        
       async private void AddToList_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            await _connection.CreateTableAsync<Bmodel>();
            string BirdNames = BirdNameCall.Text;
            var voel = new Bmodel { Bname = BirdNames};
            await _connection.InsertAsync(voel);
            
          await  DisplayAlert(BirdNames, "added to list", "Ok");
        }
```

And here is where I get from database to a listview

```
    public class Bmodel
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set;}

        
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string Bname { get; set; }
        
    }
    public partial class myBirdList : ContentPage
    {
        private SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection;
        private ObservableCollection<Bmodel> _birds;
        public myBirdList()
        { 
            InitializeComponent();
            _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();     
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {

            await _connection.CreateTableAsync<Bmodel>();
            var blists = await _connection.Table<Bmodel>().OrderBy(x => x.Bname).ToListAsync();
            _birds = new ObservableCollection<Bmodel>(blists);
            birdlistview.ItemsSource = _birds;
            
            base.OnAppearing();
        }

         void MenuItem_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var blists = (sender as MenuItem).CommandParameter as Bmodel;
            _connection.DeleteAsync(blists);
            _birds.Remove(blists);
        }
```

When an item is added twice or more to the database it display's in the listview. I would appreciate help on how to not display the duplicate items or even how to display alert when it is already in the database. I think it has something to do with the PrimaryKey if I am not mistaken. Any help would be great Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want two or more items to have the same `Bname` why not make it the `Primary Key`?

Comment: I have tried that. When I add `Bname` for the second time the application closes. Is there a way to display an alert that `Bname` is already added to database ?

Comment: Getting any exception ? Have you tried moving your `InsertAsync `method inside a `try-catch block`

Comment: check for existing data BEFORE you do the insert, or use the PK attribute.  If your application crashes when you do X, then figure out what is causing the crash and fix it.

Comment: The exception I am getting is that "Error writting to debug stream. Details: Cannot access a disposed object." How would I check for `Bname` before I `InsertAsync`?

Comment: Maybe you could create a collection to store the `Bname`,then when you want to `InsertAsync` a new `Bname`,you could  compare whethert it's already in the collection.

Comment: Still struggling with this. Is there a way to check if there is a `Bname` in the database already ? Then when a duplicate is added it will just display that a `Bname` is already added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all I changed was to keep my `Public int Id` as the `Primary Key` and change the `Bname` to `[Unique]` and where I used `InsertAsync` I changed it to `InsertOrReplaceAsync`